# MySQL Current date

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to have user can see their today picture uploaded on profile page.

Is this correct?

```
SELECT * FROM pictures 
WHERE userid = '$userid'
ORDER BY pictureuploaddate < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Still not working. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would get something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pictures 
WHERE userid = '$userid' AND 
      DATE(pictureuploaddate) = CURDATE() # Match date without time
ORDER BY pictureuploaddate DESC
```

Why do you `ORDER BY` and use an `=` in it? It should be todays date, just add it to the WHERE. If you want to get the latest picture first you can `ORDER BY pictureuploaddate DESC`

Also it's better to compare dates instead of smaller than if you want current date. Because it is faster to match.

Comment: `DATE(pictureuploaddate) = CURDATE()` will not use an index. Best to do `pictureuploaddate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 86399 SECOND`

Comment: I don't know if he has an index at the pictureuploaddate, if not, this is faster.

Answer (score 2):

This will order by a boolean result of the comparison:

```
ORDER BY pictureuploaddate < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

I'm guessing you want the comparison in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE userid = '$userid'
AND pictureuploaddate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 86399 SECOND
ORDER BY pictureuploaddate DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you picked an answer already, but to avoid any confusion with multiple uploads on the same day, you could have also done:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pictures 
WHERE userid = '$userid'
ORDER BY pictureuploaddate DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are now trying to order the results by the output of a boolean test on the date. Adding that part to the WHERE-clause makes more sense.